# Datatables find column name

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the following code in DataTables to draw the table:

```
projectRevenue = $('#projectRevenue').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    scrollX: true,
    stateSave: true,
    ajax: {
            url: "...",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON"
        },
    columns: [
        { name: 'id', data: 'id' , searchable: false , visible: false },
        { name: 'year', data: 'year' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'product_code', data: 'product_code' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'jan', data: 'jan' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'feb', data: 'feb' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'mar', data: 'mar' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'apr', data: 'apr' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'may', data: 'may' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'jun', data: 'jun' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'jul', data: 'jul' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'aug', data: 'aug' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'sep', data: 'sep' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'oct', data: 'oct' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'nov', data: 'nov' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
        { name: 'dec', data: 'dec' , searchable: true , visible: true , className: "rev_update" },
...
```

In order to be able to manipulate the data, I insert some attributes for each td with this configuration:

```
columnDefs: [{
      "targets": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
      "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        $(td).attr('contenteditable','true');
        $(td).attr('data-id',rowData.id);
      }
    }],
```

I would like to add the name of the column as an attribute but I can't find anywhere a way to get this data. So I would like something like:

```
$(td).attr('data-id',columns(this).name);
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was unsuccessful, since `this` in your context is not what you think it is. I guess, following code would get you expected result:

```
const dataTable = $('#projectRevenue').DataTable();
$(td).attr('data-id', dataTable.column(col).header().innerText)
```

However, if you wish to refer to source data object property, you may do:

```
const dataTable = $('#projectRevenue').DataTable();
$(td).attr('data-id', dataTable.column(col).dataSrc())
```